# Pairing Files and Manipulating

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of files:

```
Fair_20151026-1940.txt
Poke_20160101-1920.txt
Fair_20160101-1920.txt
Poke_20151026-1940.txt
```

I want to read each 'pair' e.g. each file that has a matching `*_YYYYMMDD-XXXX.txt` and then 'do stuff' with these files.

There may be hundreds of these and I need to ensure that for each one I can find its pair.

So far I'm simply reading in every *.xml file and comparing them to the previously read *.xml file and if it's not a match iterate. Not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing things.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Group-Object` to group each pair together:

```
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files *.txt |Where-Object { $_ -match '^(?<=Fair|Poke)_\d{8}-\d{4}\.txt$' } 
$txtFiles |Group-Object {
  $_.Name -split '_',2 |Select-Object -Skip 1
} |ForEach-Object {
  $Fair,$Poke = $_.Group |Sort-Object Name
  # Manipulate all you want here
}
```